# Gmapping does not correctly set up map size parameters

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using gmapping in ros indigo for the first time (using Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 laser scanner and wheel encoders), but I am having problems setting the map size.
I am trying to create a 10x10m map with a resolution of 0.05m as an initial test run. I run the gmapping node using this node description in the launch file:

```
<node pkg = "gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="maxUrange" value="5.0/>
    <param name="xmin" value="-5.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-5.0/>
    <param name="xmax" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="5.0/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="maxRange" value="6.0"/>
</node>
```

When the gmapping node launches, at first the parameters seem to initialise correctly.

```
PARAMETERS
/rosdistro: indigo
/rosversion: 1.11.10
/slam_gmapping/delta: 0.05
/slam_gmapping/map_update_interval: 2.0
/slam_gmapping/maxRange: 6.0
/slam_gmapping/maxUrange: 5.0
/slam_gmapping/xmax: 5.0
/slam_gmapping/xmin: -5.0
/slam_gmapping/ymax: 5.0
/slam_gmapping/ymin: -5.0

NODES
/slam_gmapping (gmapping/slam_gmapping)
```

However, when I check the map metadata using rostopic echo, I get a map of size 5120x14592. The resolution is correct. I have noticed that each time I launch the gmapping node, the size of the map changes but it is never 10x10 as I intended. The same size problems are reflected when I view the map in rviz.

```
map_load_time:
secs: 0
nsecs: 0
resolution: 0.0500000007451
width: 5120
height: 14592
origin:
position:
x: -5.0
y: -5.0
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.0
w: 1.0
```

I have seen this issue posted on ros forums before, however I believe I am setting up the launch file as advised and it still doesn't work.

link: http://answers.ros.org/question/112336/how-can-i-change-the-map-size-and-the-origin/

link: http://answers.ros.org/question/56114/how-to-change-width-of-the-map-generated-by-gmapping/

link: http://answers.ros.org/question/30038/gmapping-output-very-large-4000x4000/

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217598/gmapping-does-not-correctly-set-up-map-size-parameters/) by [steph_v](https://answers.ros.org/users/23866/steph_v/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` parameters set the initial map size; not the final map size. If your sensor sees past the initial map bounds during the map-building process, gmapping will expand the map bounds to include the new data.

How large is the area you're trying to map?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [steph_v](https://answers.ros.org/users/23866/steph_v/) on 2015-09-14**:
Thanks ahendrix.
The map is being used for short range path planning for a wheelchair. There is no limitation on where the wheelchair can travel so the total map area is potentially infinite, but I only want to keep/use map information in a ~5m radius around the chair.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-14**:
gmapping keeps an aggregate of the entire area that it has seen, for the entire time that it has been running, and it's generally intended for large-scale navigation. I don't think it's appropriate for your application.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-14**:
You may want to investigate a combination of the laser_scan_matcher and costmap_2d packages, or you may want to see if the hector project has something applicable.

**Comment by [steph_v](https://answers.ros.org/users/23866/steph_v/) on 2015-09-14**:
Thanks for that.  I'll have a look into those.

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2020-12-03**:
If it expands the initial map, does it have any impact?